# Change button text from WordPress posts

Tags: wordpress

First of all, I have zero knowledge of PHP.

I would like to add a button to each of my blog posts that will have the same text as "Your_Promo". Later I will translate that "Your_Promo" with another text like "Hosting Deal", later could be "Cheap Domain", and so on.

I use the below code in my functions.pho, but it doesn't work.

```
function custom_wc_translations($translated){

    $text = array(
        'Your_Promo' => 'Hosting Deal',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20 );
```

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in your active theme functions.php file:**

```
function vh_excerpt_read_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...  <a class="excerpt-read-more" href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="'. __( 'Read ', 'domain_name' ) . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post->ID ) ).'">'. __( 'Your_Promo &raquo;', 'domain_name' ) .'</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'vh_excerpt_read_more' );
```

Tested & working for me
See the result below: [image: Result]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My button is not the "Read more" button. I'll add CTA buttons in every single blog post. And I'll place "Your_Promo" as the CTA text of that buttons.

This "Your_Promo" text will be changed depending on my offers. If I want to change the CTA text from every post it will take a huge time to edit the posts. So I want to translate the CTA text instead.

Comment: @ZiaurRahman You can change the button name "Show more" to "Your_Promo".

Comment: @ZiaurRahman Answer updated please check again.